# fabric js bold italic not working because of font styles object in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas, fabricjs

I am facing 1 typical issue in fabric js, I am converting canvas to json using `canvas.toJson` and saved it into database. Later i am loading that json into canvas using `loadFromJSON` which all working ok.

Now issue is, i have json which has many layers and one layer is textbox which has some styles on fonts, so `json` of that layer is like,

```
 {
     "type":"textbox",
     "originX":"center",
     "originY":"top",
     "left":1200.84,
     "top":573.63,
     "width":312.81,
     "height":127.46,
     "fill":"rgb(0, 0, 0)",
     "stroke":null,
     "strokeWidth":1,
     "strokeDashArray":null,
     "strokeLineCap":"butt",
     "strokeLineJoin":"miter",
     "strokeMiterLimit":10,
     "scaleX":1,
     "scaleY":1,
     "angle":0,
     "flipX":false,
     "flipY":false,
     "opacity":1,
     "shadow":null,
     "visible":true,
     "clipTo":null,
     "backgroundColor":"",
     "fillRule":"nonzero",
     "globalCompositeOperation":"source-over",
     "transformMatrix":null,
     "lockMovementX":false,
     "lockMovementY":false,
     "evented":true,
     "overrideSecondary":1,
     "text":"NATURAL\nVENEERS",
     "fontSize":63,
     "fontWeight":"",
     "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
     "fontStyle":"",
     "lineHeight":0.9,
     "textDecoration":"",
     "textAlign":"left",
     "textBackgroundColor":"",
     "styles":{
        "0":{
           "0":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "1":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "2":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "3":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "4":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "5":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "6":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "7":{
              "fontSize":62.666651
           }
        },
        "1":{
           "0":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "1":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "2":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "3":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "4":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "5":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           },
           "6":{
              "fontSize":62.666651,
              "fontFamily":"'trebuchet ms'",
              "fontWeight":"",
              "fontStyle":""
           }
        }
     },
     "minWidth":20
  },
```

After load `json` i am doing bold and italic effect using this code.

```
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "bold");
canvas.renderAll();
```

Which is working but when i do this,

```
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "");
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "100");
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "normal");
```

It will not working. After some investigation i can figure that `styles` attribute from json causing the issue, If i remove styles from main `json` object using this code,

```
delete index['styles'];
```

Then `bold`, `italic` and `normal` text works for me. See how it behaving before removing and after removing `styles` [HERE](http://screencast.com/t/MDIVaptPQsM0).

What is the possible solution for this?

Comment: You do not provide enough information to solve the problem. The object property `.styles` is not part of the fabric.js API, nor is the object type `type : "textBox",` there are a few more no standard properties as well. Though I would just remove the styles anyways, it is completely redundant information. Don't use `delete` it stuffs up Javascript optimization, use `index.styles = undefined;` befor you stringify the fabric JSON object.

Comment: @Blindman67 what other information should i provide you to reach to issue?

Comment: The information is fine. This is actually a bug in fabricjs that should be fixed or at least refined. I will try to take care of it. There is no answer now that can be given other than "delete fontWeight from style every object in style object" every  time. i will post as an answer just as reference.

Comment: there was a missing clone function on some style object that was the problem. You should try if new version are still affected. Consider that you have to create the text object with new version and not just reload it.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi what is the latest version of fabricjs?

Answer (score 1):

as of now with current fabricjs version there is this problem.

You can just delete the fontWeight property every time you set one new.

example:

```
function cleanFontWeightStyle(obj) {
    if (obj.styles) {
        var style = obj.styles;
        for (rowIndex in style) {
            var row = style[rowIndex];
            for (letterIndex in row) {
                letter = row[letterIndex];
                if (letter.fontWeight && letter.fontWeight=='') {
                    delete letter['fontWeight'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ugly. This should be fixed in the library itself that should not create meaningless styles objects.

Comment: ok let me try. but what if i have to set part of font bold in string?

Comment: this will delete jsut the fontWeight not set or set to empty string, if you set part to bold, bold is different from false and from '' so it will not delete it, it will stay. Give it a tray because i did not.

Comment: how can i restore it to my original object after perform deletion?

Comment: removed `fontWeight` from object. but still same issue.

Comment: i checked your video, it may be a bug of textbox itself.

Comment: so any solution for this? as i replaced js with this one http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js that issue solved but now text align not working.